# How to avoid writing a row.names column when saving a data.frame using the xlsx package

Tags: r, dataframe, xlsx

I have a data frame like this one below and I really want to remove the row names when I export it to a excel file using the xlsx package.

```
bd <- data.frame(id = 1:200, A = c(rep("One", 100), rep("Two", 100)), 
             B = c(rep(1,50), rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50)))
```

I have already tried to use the command below, but it keep them in the first column of the excel file.

```
bd <- data.frame(id = 1:200, A = c(rep("One", 100), rep("Two", 100)), 
             B = c(rep(1,50), rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50)), row.names=NULL)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is it about the row names that is causing problems?

Comment: I am saving the data.frame in a excel worksheet using the xlsx package. However it keeps the row.names as the first column of the file.

Comment: Hint: Whenever you have a problem and you want to solve it here - describe the actual problem at hand.  In this case your problem was that the row names are exported as well and you don't want that.

Comment: @Dason You are right. Actually I thought that it was easier than it appear. I will change the question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set the rownames to `NULL` to remove them:

```
rownames(bd) <- NULL
```

Also, from xlsx documentation:

```
write.xlsx(x, file, sheetName="Sheet1",
           col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE)
```

Set row.names to `FALSE` to avoid the first column being row names.

Comment: @ Andy Garcia, you got it! However I thought that it was easier than it appears.

Comment: @DWin Indeed, I was mildly surprised at what happened to the data frame when I ran `attributes(bd)$row.names <- NULL`.

Comment: If `append = T,` and `row.names = F` this throws an error for every sheet you `write.xlsx` after the first one to the same workbook.  `Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  method setCellValue with signature ([Ljava/lang/String;)V not found
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(value)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: packages `xlsx` and `XLConnect` seem to be loaded with frustrating errors/bugs [Weird behavior lapplying XLConnect functions to list of workbooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107970/weird-behavior-lapplying-xlconnect-functions-to-list-of-workbooks?noredirect=1#comment69420543_41107970)

Comment: @Tunn First the data needs to be set as a data frame. `write.xlsx(as.data.frame(x), file, sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE)`  So there is no problem. This is described in the [link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/write-xlsx-row-names-false/27130) .