# Removing display of row names from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, printing, output-formatting

I am creating a dataframe using this code:

```
df <- data.frame(dbGetQuery(con, paste('select * from test')))
```

Which results in this:

```
    UID      BuildingCode   AccessTime
1   123456   BUILD-1        2014-06-16 07:00:00
2   364952   BUILD-2        2014-06-15 08:00:00
3    95865   BUILD-1        2014-06-06 09:50:00
```

I am then trying to remove the row names (1, 2, 3, etc) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117629/how-to-avoid-writing-a-row-names-column-when-saving-a-data-frame-using-the-xlsx) by using this code:

```
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

But then when I print out `df` it still displays the row names. Is there a way to not include the row names when creating the data frame? I found a suggestion about `row.name = FALSE` but when I tried it I just got errors (I might have placed it in the wrong place).

**EDIT:** What I want to do is convert the dateframe to a HTML table and I don't want the row name to be present in the table.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "when I print out df". Is `row.names = FALSE` in `write.table` relevant?

Comment: @Henrik probably offers the best solution here. I wonder though why doing something like `attributes(df)$row.names <- NULL` erases all values form df

Comment: What I mean by "when I print out df" is I type `df` into the terminal which then prints out the data frame. I don't have `write.table` because I'm not writing a table (and when I do I'm going to be using xtable).

Comment: so just `print(df, row.names = F)` should do

Comment: @DavidArenburg your correct, that works! But how would I put that into a html table?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You have successfully removed the row names. The `print.data.frame` method just shows the row numbers if no row names are present.

```
df1 <- data.frame(values = rnorm(3), group = letters[1:3],
                  row.names = paste0("RowName", 1:3))
print(df1)
#            values group
#RowName1 -1.469809     a
#RowName2 -1.164943     b
#RowName3  0.899430     c

rownames(df1) <- NULL
print(df1)
#     values group
#1 -1.469809     a
#2 -1.164943     b
#3  0.899430     c
```

You can suppress printing the row names and numbers in `print.data.frame` with the argument `row.names` as `FALSE`.

```
print(df1, row.names = FALSE)
#     values group
# -1.4345829     d
#  0.2182768     e
# -0.2855440     f
```

**Edit:** As written in the comments, you want to convert this to HTML. From the `xtable` and `print.xtable` documentation, you can see that the argument `include.rownames` will do the trick.

```
library("xtable")
print(xtable(df1), type="html", include.rownames = FALSE)
#<!-- html table generated in R 3.1.0 by xtable 1.7-3 package -->
#<!-- Thu Jun 26 12:50:17 2014 -->
#<TABLE border=1>
#<TR> <TH> values </TH> <TH> group </TH>  </TR>
#<TR> <TD align="right"> -0.34 </TD> <TD> a </TD> </TR>
#<TR> <TD align="right"> -1.04 </TD> <TD> b </TD> </TR>
#<TR> <TD align="right"> -0.48 </TD> <TD> c </TD> </TR>
#</TABLE>
```

Comment: After doing as I said above, when I do `attributes(df)` I get this result: `$row.names [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15`. Does this not indicate that the row names are still there? Basically what I want to do is convert the DF to a HTML table and I just don't want the row name to be present.

Comment: @DomAbbott From the R docs, a `data.frame` is "is a `list` of variables of the same number of rows with unique row names, given class '`data.frame`'. If no variables are included, the row names determine the number of rows." Hence row names are always present in the attributes. How do you do your conversion?

Comment: What do you mean by conversion? I am using this code to create a html table `print(xtable(df), type="html", file="example.html")` but this includes the row names.

Comment: @DomAbbott add this comment to your post, so we know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DomAbbott I've edited so you get what you want. You need to use the `include.rownames` argument.

Answer (score 41):

Yes I know it is over half a year later and a tad late, BUT

```
row.names(df) <- NULL
```

does work. For me at least :-)

And if you have important information in row.names like dates for example, what I do is just :

```
df$Dates <- as.Date(row.names(df))
```

This will add a new column on the end but if you want it at the beginning of your data frame

```
df <- df[,c(7,1,2,3,4,5,6,...)]
```

Hope this helps those from Google :)

Answer (score 16):

If you want to format your table via `kable`, you can use `row.names = F`

```
kable(df, row.names = F)
```

Answer (score 8):

A `dplyr` solution :

```
df = df %>% `rownames<-`( NULL )
```

Comment: This isn't a "dplyr solution". If anything it's a magrittr solution. But a much simpler solution would be to just call rownames(df) <- NULL.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72318941/8806649 for `tidyverse` solution

Answer (score 5):

...or simply:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_data_with_rownames %>%
SOME STUFF %>%
tibble::remove_rownames() -> wrangled_df_data_without_rownames
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had the same problem when using htmlTable() (‘htmlTable’ package) and I found a simpler solution: convert the data frame to a matrix with as.matrix():

```
htmlTable(as.matrix(df))
```

And be sure that the rownames are just indices. as.matrix() conservs the same columnames. That's it.

## UPDATE

Following the comment of @DMR, I did't notice that `htmlTable()` has the parameter `rnames = FALSE` for cases like this. So a better answer would be:

```
htmlTable(df, rnames = FALSE)
```

Comment: htmlTable has the ```rnames``` parameter for this:

```htmlTable(df, rnames = FALSE)```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is intended for comment though but since i havent got enough reputation, i think it will still be relevant as an answer and help some one.

I find `datatable` in `library DT` robust to handle `rownames`, and `columnames`

```
Library DT
datatable(df, rownames = FALSE)  # no row names
```

refer to https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ for usage scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is assigning `c()` to your `rownames` to get rid of your row names like this (thanks @Anders for data):

```r
df <- data.frame(values = rnorm(3), group = letters[1:3],
                  row.names = paste0("RowName", 1:3))
df
#>             values group
#> RowName1 0.4189236     a
#> RowName2 1.8604397     b
#> RowName3 0.7030387     c
rownames(df) <- c()
print(df)
#>      values group
#> 1 0.4189236     a
#> 2 1.8604397     b
#> 3 0.7030387     c
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that `data.table` has an option for removing rownames when printing `data.table`'s.

`options(datatable.print.rownames = F)`

This solved my problem in the console and when rendering RMarkdown files. See other printing options [here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/print.data.table.html)

Answer (score 0):

simply try rownames(df) <- ""