# Create xts object from CSV

Tags: r, date, csv, xts

I'm trying to generate an xts from a CSV file. The output looks okay as a simple vector i.e. `Date` and `Value` columns are character and numeric, respectively.

However, if I want to make it into an xts, the output seems dubious
I'm wondering what is the output on the furthest left column on the xts?

```
> test <- read.csv("Test.csv", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
> test
    Date Value
1 1/12/2014   1.5
2 2/12/2014   0.9
3 1/12/2015  -0.1
4 2/12/2015  -0.3
5 1/12/2016  -0.7
6 2/12/2016   0.2
7 7/12/2016  -1.0
8 8/12/2016  -0.2
9 9/12/2016  -1.1
> xts(test, order.by = as.POSIXct(test$Date), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
           Date        Value 
0001-12-20 "1/12/2014" " 1.5"
0001-12-20 "1/12/2015" "-0.1"
0001-12-20 "1/12/2016" "-0.7"
0002-12-20 "2/12/2014" " 0.9"
0002-12-20 "2/12/2015" "-0.3"
0002-12-20 "2/12/2016" " 0.2"
0007-12-20 "7/12/2016" "-1.0"
0008-12-20 "8/12/2016" "-0.2"
0009-12-20 "9/12/2016" "-1.1"
```

I'd simply like to set an xts ordered by `Date`, rather than the mystery column on the left. I've tried `as.Date` for the xts as well but have the same results.

Comment: The column on the left is in fact not a column but rather the names of the rows ( or rather `row.names` in R). You [cannot really get rid of it except changing the names displayed usually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428051/removing-display-of-r-row-names-from-data-frame].
By the I think you are using the package `xts` , so perhaps you should add that you use it, in your question so we can identify quicker what you are referring to.

Comment: Try this  `testXts = xts(test[,-1], order.by = as.Date(test[,1], format = "%d/%m/%Y"))`. Note the typo in your statement `format` should be parameter of `as.Date` and not `xts` function.

Comment: Ahhh that explains a lot - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use `read.zoo` to read the data from CSV, then convert the result to xts using `as.xts`.

```
Text <- "Date,Value
1/12/2014,1.5
2/12/2014,0.9
1/12/2015,-0.1
2/12/2015,-0.3
1/12/2016,-0.7
2/12/2016,0.2
7/12/2016,-1.0
8/12/2016,-0.2
9/12/2016,-1.1"
z <- read.zoo(text=Text, sep=",", header=TRUE, format="%m/%d/%Y", drop=FALSE)
x <- as.xts(z)
#            Value
# 2014-01-12   1.5
# 2014-02-12   0.9
# 2015-01-12  -0.1
# 2015-02-12  -0.3
# 2016-01-12  -0.7
# 2016-02-12   0.2
# 2016-07-12  -1.0
# 2016-08-12  -0.2
# 2016-09-12  -1.1
```

Note that you will need to omit `text = Text` from your actual call, and replace it with `file = "your_file_name.csv"`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be twofold. One, there is a misplaced parenthesis in one of your calls; two, the left most column is the index, making the `Date` column superfluous.

```
df <- read.table(text="
  Date Value
  1/12/2014   1.5
  2/12/2014   0.9
  1/12/2015  -0.1
  2/12/2015  -0.3
  1/12/2016  -0.7
  2/12/2016   0.2
  7/12/2016  -1.0
  8/12/2016  -0.2
  9/12/2016  -1.1",
  header=TRUE)

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

library(xts)
xts(df[-1], order.by=df[,1])

#            Value
# 2014-12-01   1.5
# 2014-12-02   0.9
# 2015-12-01  -0.1
# 2015-12-02  -0.3
# 2016-12-01  -0.7
# 2016-12-02   0.2
# 2016-12-07  -1.0
# 2016-12-08  -0.2
# 2016-12-09  -1.1
```