# Creating names for a matrix of data in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a simple `12 x 2` matrix called `m` that contains my dataset (see below).

## Question

I was wondering why when I use `dimnames(m)` to **create two names for the two columns of my data**, I run into an `Error`? Is there a better way to create column names for this data in R?

**Here is my R code:**

```
Group1 = rnorm(6, 7)  ;  Group2 = rnorm(6, 9)
Level = gl(n = 2, k = 6)

m = matrix(c(Group1 , Group2, Level), nrow = 12, ncol = 2)
dimnames(m) <- list( DV = Group1, Level = Level)
```

Comment: You want `colnames`, not `dimnames` -- `dimnames` is used to provide `colnames` and `rownames` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace dimnames(m) with

```
colnames(m) <- c("DV","Level")
```

Comment: So in text, what would the last column name look like? 'Level_1_12' or something like that?

Comment: I see what you mean.  The way R works, the first column you are looking at is actually internal row numbers.  They cannot have a column name assigned, because they're not actually part of the data set.

Comment: i don't think this works with a matrix,
 but it does with a data.frame.  if this is just for presentation purposes, maybe convert to a data.frame before 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428051/removing-display-of-r-row-names-from-data-frame