# Automatic index for x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use automatic index for x-axis in ggplot2.
My data set is followed:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ElemStatLearn)
phoneme <- as_tibble(phoneme)
aa = phoneme %>% 
  filter(g == "aa")
```

This is a phoneme data, recording 256 frequencies for each 695 data.

With base code, I can do as follows:
(Let's do only 15 of 695 data)

```
aa[1:15, 1:256]
min_l = min( aa[1:15, 1:256] )
max_l = max( aa[1:15, 1:256] )

ii=1
plot( as.double(aa[ii, 1:256]), ylim=c(min_l,max_l), type="l", col="green", xlab="Frequency")
for( ii in 2:15 ){
  lines( as.double(aa[ii,]), col="green" )
}
```

But when I try to do it using ggplot2, I'm confused.

What should I put in `aes`?

```
ggplot(data = aa, aes(x = 1:256, y = aa[1, 1:256])) + geom_line()
```

returns an error. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ElemStatLearn)
phoneme <- as_tibble(phoneme)
aa = phoneme %>% 
  filter(g == "aa")

aa[1:15, 1:256]
min_l = min( aa[1:15, 1:256] )
max_l = max( aa[1:15, 1:256] )

ii=1
plot( as.double(aa[ii, 1:256]), ylim=c(min_l,max_l), type="l", col="green", 
xlab="Frequency")
for( ii in 2:15 ){
  lines( as.double(aa[ii,]), col="green" )
}
```

[image]

```
library(reshape2)
aa2 <- aa %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1:15) %>%  
  dplyr::select(-g, -speaker) %>% 
  t %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::add_rownames() %>% 
  dplyr::select(-rowname) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(id = 1:256) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars = "id")

ggplot2::ggplot(aa2) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = id, y = value, col = variable), show.legend = F) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 250, 50)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min_l,max_l)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = rep("green", 256)) +
  xlab("Frequency") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

---

Comment:

When manipulated the dataframe to perform the transposed matrix, the object under manipulation acquires the names of the varibles in each row (`rownames`). So, to make the plot easier and make the df more elegant I think it is interesting to remove the names of the rows.

So it was necessary at first to include the names in the df and (`dplyr::add_rownames()`) later to remove the column with the names of the rows (`dplyr::select(-rowname)`) .

This gives a false illusion of error, but I performed in a redundant way to avoid using `NULL`. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428051/removing-display-of-row-names-from-data-frame).

---

Editing by Gregor's comment:

```
aa2 <- aa %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1:15) %>%  
  dplyr::select(-g, -speaker) %>% 
  t %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  tibble::remove_rownames() %>% # Comment
  dplyr::mutate(id = 1:256) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars = "id")
```

Comment: Nice answer! But what's the point of `add_rownames %>% select(-rowname)`, seems like `x + 1 - 1`. And `add_rownames` is deprecated in current versions, recommending `tibble::rownames_to_column` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this trick of  `+1-1` was unfortunately required to avoid using `NULL`.

Comment: I haven't run the code to see, but I don't understand what you mean by "avoid using `NULL`. I think it would at least be worth a comment/explanation in the answer, since at a glance it looks like a mistake.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. In that case, I'd suggest using `tibble::remove_rownames()` instead. Much clearer.