# Turning off Automatic Row Numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
table_a = structure(list(elephant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L), elephant_status = c("performing", "performing", 
"performing", "performing", "performing", "performing", "performing", 
"performing", "performing", "performing", "performing", "performing"
), year = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2015L, 2018L, 2019L, 2016L, 2021L), year_escaped = c("2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2015", "NULL", 
"NULL", "NULL", "NULL")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

When I view this table, a automatic column of row numbers is displayed on the left:

```
   elephant elephant_status year year_escaped
1         1      performing 2015         2018
2         1      performing 2016         2018
3         1      performing 2017         2018
4         1      performing 2018         2018
5         2      performing 2018         2022
6         2      performing 2019         2022
7         2      performing 2020         2022
8         3      performing 2015         2015
9         4      performing 2018         NULL
10        4      performing 2019         NULL
11        5      performing 2016         NULL
12        5      performing 2021         NULL
```

I tried to consult other posts (e.g. [Removing display of row names from data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428051/removing-display-of-row-names-from-data-frame)) and try the advice given there, e.g.

```
rownames(table_a) = NULL
```

But the row numbers still appear on the left:

```
   elephant elephant_status year year_escaped
1         1      performing 2015         2018
2         1      performing 2016         2018
3         1      performing 2017         2018
4         1      performing 2018         2018
5         2      performing 2018         2022
6         2      performing 2019         2022
7         2      performing 2020         2022
8         3      performing 2015         2015
9         4      performing 2018         NULL
10        4      performing 2019         NULL
11        5      performing 2016         NULL
12        5      performing 2021         NULL
```

Is it possible to write R code such that when you display the table, these row numbers on the left are not shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think i just found an answer?

```
print.data.frame(table_a, row.names = FALSE)
```

Now, the row numbers are gone!

```
 elephant elephant_status year year_escaped
        1      performing 2015         2018
        1      performing 2016         2018
        1      performing 2017         2018
        1      performing 2018         2018
        2      performing 2018         2022
        2      performing 2019         2022
        2      performing 2020         2022
        3      performing 2015         2015
        4      performing 2018         NULL
        4      performing 2019         NULL
        5      performing 2016         NULL
        5      performing 2021         NULL
```