# Weird behavior lapplying XLConnect functions to list of workbooks

Tags: r, loops, xlconnect

## Part 1:

I am trying to rename worksheets in a list of workbooks using `lapply` and `XLConnect` (I need to rename them for the next part of the code to run properly, more on this in part 2):

```
library(XLConnect)

# testWB.xlsx contains a blank worksheet called Sheet1
testWB <- rep(lapply("testWB.xlsx", loadWorkbook), 3)

lapply(1:length(testWB), function(x) {
  renameSheet(testWB[[x]], "Sheet1", "test1")
})
```

Gives me the error:

```
`Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..0)`
```

But:

```
renameSheet(testWB[[1]], "Sheet1", "test1")
```

Renames the sheet as it is supposed to.  It is weird, `renameSheet` does NOT work with lapply, but `getActiveSheetIndex` does work with lapply.

```
unlist(lapply(1:length(testWB), function(x) {
  getActiveSheetIndex(testWB[[x]])
}))
[1] 1 1 1
```

I've tested other `XLConnect` functions and some work in lapply and others do not.

## Part 2:

I need to rename sheets to get the `writeWorksheet` function to work.  E.g.:

```
cell_data <- c("Larry", "Curly", "Moe")

unlist(lapply(1:length(testWB), function(x) {
  writeWorksheet(testWB[[x]], cell_data[x], sheet = "sheet1", header = F)
  readWorksheet(testWB[[x]], "Sheet1", header = F)
}))
Col1    Col1    Col1 
"Larry" "Curly"   "Moe"
```

But looking at testWB after running the above loop:

```
unlist(lapply(1:length(testWB), function(x) {
  readWorksheet(testWB[[x]], "Sheet1", header = F)
}))
Col1  Col1  Col1 
"Moe" "Moe" "Moe"
```

As you can see this ends up inputting `Moe` into all of the A1 cells of each sheet in each workbook instead of `Larry, Curly, Moe` in A1 cell of each respective workbook.  If the workbook sheets have different names (e.g., Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3) then it works properly.  Hence my issue in part one.

Since I have not gotten this to work, I have had to reconstruct `testWB.xlsx` templates in R and reapply formatting. `testWB.xlsx` in reality is quite a nuanced excel form so recreating it is not ideal.

I hope I am just missing something small and thank you in advance for any suggestions.

`XLConnect` version 0.2-12

Comment: It would seem more direct to iterate over the items in the list rather than use the index. Does `lapply(testWB, function(x) {renameSheet(x, "Sheet1", "test1")})` work?

Comment: @MrFlick Have tried: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘renameSheet’ for signature ‘"integer", "character"’`

Comment: It thinks `x` is an integer in that case? That doesn't seem right. What is `class(testWB[[1]])`?

Comment: @MrFlick `[1] "workbook"
attr(,"package")
[1] "XLConnect`